# Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth'

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

Getting this error when using angularfire. Have checked my imports and they seem to be correct. I have tried to reinstall angularfire however it is still throwing this error. Is there issues with angularfire?

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from "../services/user";
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {
  userData: any; // Save logged in user data

  constructor(
    public afs: AngularFirestore,   // Inject Firestore service
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, // Inject Firebase auth service
    public router: Router,  
    public ngZone: NgZone // NgZone service to remove outside scope warning
  ) {    
    /* Saving user data in localstorage when 
    logged in and setting up null when logged out */
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.userData = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('user', null);
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      }
    })
  }

  // Sign in with email/password
  SignIn(email, password) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        });
        this.SetUserData(result.user);
      }).catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error.message)
      })
  }
```

Comment: Did you import the module?

Comment: in case anyone else has my issue, you used to be able to reference firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(...) directly, so make sure you now add AngularFireAuth to the constructor and reference this.afAuth.onAuthStateChanged(...)

Answer (score 55):

Had the same problem.
Seems starting `"@angular/fire": "^6.0.0"` AngularFireAuth has dropped the auth property.

Just delete `auth` & it should work

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2409#issuecomment-615993136

Comment: Most places yes. Not with firebaseui as in this.ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(this.afAuth); will not work

Comment: Does not work for Angular9. Removing auth gives a new error "signInWithEmailAndPassword does not exist on type AngularFireAuth"

Answer (score 9):

Just delete the "auth", and it will work

[Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth' #2409](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2409#issuecomment-615993136)

Comment: Worked for me, Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and it was related to version mismatch in `package.json`.
I had

```
dependencies {
        ...
        "@angular/fire": "latest", // It was 6.0.0
        "firebase": "5.4.2",
        ...
}
```

Then I changed to

```
dependencies {
        ...
        "@angular/fire": "5.4.2",
        "firebase": "5.4.2",
        ...
}
```

Also ensure to import `AngularFireAuthModule` in your `app.module.ts`

```
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';

...
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        AngularFireAuthModule
    ],
    ....
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 4):

You should import the right Firebase:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

and then for example:

```
// Sign in with Google
GoogleAuth(): any {
    return this.AuthLogin(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

hello noce if it's the truth but this worked for me

1 - npm uninstall firebase @angular/fire

2- package.json

3 - dependencies {
        ...
        "@angular/fire": "6.0.0",
        "firebase": "7.14.1",
        ...
}

4 - change

dependencies {
        ...
        "@angular/fire": "^5.4.2",

```
    ...
```

5 - save

6 - npm install firebase @angular/fire

if you find another much better solution but for now this worked

Comment: Not sure if it will solve the issue, seems like typed definition is missing because of which type error is coming up.

Answer (score 1):

This one happens because of the new update. Check the release note!
[changelog](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#7.6.2).

@angular/fire/auth
AngularFireAuth has dropped the auth property and instead Promise Proxies the underlying Firebase auth.Auth instance

Just delete the "auth", and it will work

Answer (score 1):

**Below solution worked for me**:

**1. Import firebase**

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
```

**2. then in the constructor use firebase  like this:**

```
  this.auth = firebase.auth;
```

**3. then use function like below:**

```js
this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then((result) => {
  this.ngZone.run(() => {
    this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
  });
  this.SetUserData(result.user);
}).catch((error) => {
  window.alert(error.message)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking different combinations, the latest version of **@angular/fire** that works with **Angular 9.1.6** is **5.4.2**.

Any version above would not allow you to use the **auth** AngularFireAuth property, even though I could not find any explicit deprecation notice in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/version-6-upgrade.md

"AngularFireAuth has dropped the auth property and instead Promise Proxies the underlying Firebase auth.Auth instance; allowing your development experience to more closely mirror the JS SDK. Similar changes have been made to AngularFireFunctions, AngularFireMessaging, and AngularFirePerformance."